# Cooking potato same day you dig up

Tags: food-safety, potatoes

Could you cook and eat potatoes the same day you dig them up?

Comment: What are your concerns? You tagged it food-safety. Anything particular you are worried about?

Comment: I mean, you should probably wash them first. Otherwise why any concern?

Comment: Traditionally when farmers harvested potatoes they would burn the dry leaves in a corner of the field and roast some of the freshly harvested potatoes it it as a celebratory meal.

Answer (score 10):

Absolutely! Right away if you like. And you may well notice they taste really nice when you do that. "New potatoes" - small, and not stored for long - are delicious.

Comment: Similar situation for corn. There's a point where the sugar maxes out and after that the sugar starts turning into starch. You want to pick right at that point. Picking the corn from the stalks speeds up the sugar-to-starch conversion. Ideally you want to go directly from stalk to pot/grill. If that's not possible, try to get fresh picked and cook within 24 hours. As much as 50% of the sugar will be converted by then.

Comment: oh yes, as a child our rule for corn (learned from our Mennonite neighbours) was you put the pot of water on to boil, then go out and pick the corn, and by the time you have it shucked the water should be boiling and in it goes. Marvelous.